# Transpose a wide dataset into long with multiple steps

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following dataset which has firm identifiers in column `id_isin` and a series of covariates (features) in the column `covariate`. The dataset comes in wide format as each covariate is observed at multiple time periods. These are organized in columns (`y2010` to `y2020`). I report the input data called `forSO` below:

```r
library(data.table)

forSO = fread("~/Desktop/forSO.csv")
forSO
#>         id_isin                     covariate      y2010      y2011      y2012
#> 1: ZAE000255915  NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS  8118000.0  9674000.0 8.3930e+06
#> 2: ZAE000255915              OPERATING INCOME 11756000.0 14134000.0 1.2266e+07
#> 3: ZAE000255915              RETURN ON ASSETS        2.5        2.3 1.7800e+00
#> 4: ZAE000198289 NET INC BEFORE EXTRA/PFD DIVS         NA         NA         NA
#> 5: ZAE000198289              OPERATING INCOME         NA         NA         NA
#> 6: ZAE000198289              RETURN ON ASSETS         NA         NA         NA
#>         y2013      y2014    y2015       y2016       y2017       y2018
#> 1: 1.1981e+07 1.3216e+07 14331000 14708000.00 13823000.00 13917000.00
#> 2: 1.7975e+07 1.9921e+07 21227000 22210000.00 21329000.00 21772000.00
#> 3: 1.8400e+00 1.9300e+00        2        2.06        2.01        1.91
#> 4:         NA         NA    40811   559094.00   786806.00   814462.00
#> 5:         NA         NA    48190   233141.00   299230.00   307252.00
#> 6:         NA         NA       NA       10.84       12.86       11.76
#>          y2019       y2020
#> 1: 14256000.00  5880000.00
#> 2: 21820000.00 10765000.00
#> 3:        1.87        1.09
#> 4:   920734.00   485423.00
#> 5:   368575.00   326465.00
#> 6:       11.24        5.57
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I want to transpose the dataset into a panel data structure which looks like the following:

```r
library(data.table)

output = fread("~/Desktop/minimal.csv")
output
#>          id_isin year NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS OPERATING INCOME
#>  1: ZAE000255915 2010                      8118000         11756000
#>  2: ZAE000255915 2011                      9674000         14134000
#>  3: ZAE000255915 2012                      8393000         12266000
#>  4: ZAE000255915 2013                     11981000         17975000
#>  5: ZAE000255915 2014                     13216000         19921000
#>  6: ZAE000255915 2015                     14331000         21227000
#>  7: ZAE000255915 2016                     14708000         22210000
#>  8: ZAE000255915 2017                     13823000         21329000
#>  9: ZAE000255915 2018                     13917000         21772000
#> 10: ZAE000255915 2019                     14256000         21820000
#> 11: ZAE000255915 2020                      5880000         10765000
#> 12: ZAE000198289 2010                           NA               NA
#> 13: ZAE000198289 2011                           NA               NA
#> 14: ZAE000198289 2012                           NA               NA
#> 15: ZAE000198289 2013                           NA               NA
#> 16: ZAE000198289 2014                           NA               NA
#> 17: ZAE000198289 2015                        40811            48190
#> 18: ZAE000198289 2016                       559094           233141
#> 19: ZAE000198289 2017                       786806           299230
#> 20: ZAE000198289 2018                       814462           307252
#> 21: ZAE000198289 2019                       920734           368575
#> 22: ZAE000198289 2020                       485423           326465
#>          id_isin year NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS OPERATING INCOME
#>     RETURN ON ASSETS
#>  1:             2.50
#>  2:             2.30
#>  3:             1.78
#>  4:             1.84
#>  5:             1.93
#>  6:             2.00
#>  7:             2.06
#>  8:             2.01
#>  9:             1.91
#> 10:             1.87
#> 11:             1.09
#> 12:               NA
#> 13:               NA
#> 14:               NA
#> 15:               NA
#> 16:               NA
#> 17:               NA
#> 18:            10.84
#> 19:            12.86
#> 20:            11.76
#> 21:            11.24
#> 22:             5.57
#>     RETURN ON ASSETS
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Please find both datasets to import in R below.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

**Input Dataset**

```r
structure(list(id_isin = c("ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", 
                           "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289"), 
               covariate = c("NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS", 
                             "OPERATING INCOME", "RETURN ON ASSETS", "NET INC BEFORE EXTRA/PFD DIVS", 
                             "OPERATING INCOME", "RETURN ON ASSETS"), 
               y2010 = c(8118000, 11756000, 2.5, NA, NA, NA), 
               y2011 = c(9674000, 14134000, 2.3, NA, NA, NA), 
               y2012 = c(8393000, 12266000, 1.78, NA, NA, NA), 
               y2013 = c(11981000, 17975000, 1.84, NA, NA, NA), 
               y2014 = c(13216000, 19921000, 1.93, NA, NA, NA), 
               y2015 = c(14331000L, 21227000L, 2L, 40811L, 48190L, NA), 
               y2016 = c(14708000, 22210000, 2.06, 559094, 233141, 10.84), 
               y2017 = c(13823000, 21329000, 2.01, 786806, 299230, 12.86), 
               y2018 = c(13917000, 21772000, 1.91, 814462, 307252, 11.76), 
               y2019 = c(14256000, 21820000, 1.87, 920734, 368575, 11.24), 
               y2020 = c(5880000, 10765000, 1.09, 485423, 326465, 5.57)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame" ))
```

**Desired Outcome**

```r
structure(list(id_isin = c("ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", 
                           "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", 
                           "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", 
                           "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", 
                           "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", 
                           "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289"), 
               year = c(2010L, 
                        2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 
                        2020L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
                        2018L, 2019L, 2020L), 
               `NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS` = c(8118000L, 
                                                  9674000L, 8393000L, 11981000L, 13216000L, 14331000L, 14708000L, 
                                                  13823000L, 13917000L, 14256000L, 5880000L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                  40811L, 559094L, 786806L, 814462L, 920734L, 485423L), 
               `OPERATING INCOME` = c(11756000L, 
                                      14134000L, 12266000L, 17975000L, 19921000L, 21227000L, 22210000L, 
                                      21329000L, 21772000L, 21820000L, 10765000L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                      48190L, 233141L, 299230L, 307252L, 368575L, 326465L), 
               `RETURN ON ASSETS` = c(2.5, 
                                      2.3, 1.78, 1.84, 1.93, 2, 2.06, 2.01, 1.91, 1.87, 1.09, NA, NA, 
                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, 10.84, 12.86, 11.76, 11.24, 5.57)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer data.table functions/syntax, perhaps:

```r
library(data.table)
x <- structure(list(id_isin = c("ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", 
                                "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289"), 
                    covariate = c("NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS", 
                                  "OPERATING INCOME", "RETURN ON ASSETS", "NET INC BEFORE EXTRA/PFD DIVS", 
                                  "OPERATING INCOME", "RETURN ON ASSETS"), 
                    y2010 = c(8118000, 11756000, 2.5, NA, NA, NA), 
                    y2011 = c(9674000, 14134000, 2.3, NA, NA, NA), 
                    y2012 = c(8393000, 12266000, 1.78, NA, NA, NA), 
                    y2013 = c(11981000, 17975000, 1.84, NA, NA, NA), 
                    y2014 = c(13216000, 19921000, 1.93, NA, NA, NA), 
                    y2015 = c(14331000L, 21227000L, 2L, 40811L, 48190L, NA), 
                    y2016 = c(14708000, 22210000, 2.06, 559094, 233141, 10.84), 
                    y2017 = c(13823000, 21329000, 2.01, 786806, 299230, 12.86), 
                    y2018 = c(13917000, 21772000, 1.91, 814462, 307252, 11.76), 
                    y2019 = c(14256000, 21820000, 1.87, 920734, 368575, 11.24), 
                    y2020 = c(5880000, 10765000, 1.09, 485423, 326465, 5.57)), 
               row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame" ))

x.m2 <- melt(x, id.vars = c("id_isin", "covariate"))
#> Warning in melt.data.table(x, id.vars = c("id_isin", "covariate")):
#> 'measure.vars' [y2010, y2011, y2012, y2013, ...] are not all of the same type.
#> By order of hierarchy, the molten data value column will be of type 'double'.
#> All measure variables not of type 'double' will be coerced too. Check DETAILS
#> in ?melt.data.table for more on coercion.
x.m3 <- dcast(x.m2, formula = id_isin + variable ~ covariate, value.var = "value")
x.m3$year <- as.integer(gsub(x = x.m3$variable, pattern = "y", replacement = ""))
x.m4 <- x.m3[,variable := NULL]

x.m5 <- x.m4[,`NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS` := .(fcoalesce(`NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS`,`NET INC BEFORE EXTRA/PFD DIVS`))]
x.m6 <- x.m5[,`NET INC BEFORE EXTRA/PFD DIVS` := NULL]
x.m6

outcome <- structure(list(id_isin = c("ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", 
                           "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", 
                           "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", 
                           "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", 
                           "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", 
                           "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289"), 
               year = c(2010L, 
                        2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 
                        2020L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
                        2018L, 2019L, 2020L), 
               `NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS` = c(8118000L, 
                                                  9674000L, 8393000L, 11981000L, 13216000L, 14331000L, 14708000L, 
                                                  13823000L, 13917000L, 14256000L, 5880000L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                  40811L, 559094L, 786806L, 814462L, 920734L, 485423L), 
               `OPERATING INCOME` = c(11756000L, 
                                      14134000L, 12266000L, 17975000L, 19921000L, 21227000L, 22210000L, 
                                      21329000L, 21772000L, 21820000L, 10765000L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                      48190L, 233141L, 299230L, 307252L, 368575L, 326465L), 
               `RETURN ON ASSETS` = c(2.5, 
                                      2.3, 1.78, 1.84, 1.93, 2, 2.06, 2.01, 1.91, 1.87, 1.09, NA, NA, 
                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, 10.84, 12.86, 11.76, 11.24, 5.57)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
dplyr::all_equal(x.m6, outcome)
#> [1] "- Different types for column `NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS`: double vs integer\n- Different types for column `OPERATING INCOME`: double vs integer\n"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started:

```
x <- structure(list(id_isin = c("ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", 
                           "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289"), 
               covariate = c("NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS", 
                             "OPERATING INCOME", "RETURN ON ASSETS", "NET INC BEFORE EXTRA/PFD DIVS", 
                             "OPERATING INCOME", "RETURN ON ASSETS"), 
               y2010 = c(8118000, 11756000, 2.5, NA, NA, NA), 
               y2011 = c(9674000, 14134000, 2.3, NA, NA, NA), 
               y2012 = c(8393000, 12266000, 1.78, NA, NA, NA), 
               y2013 = c(11981000, 17975000, 1.84, NA, NA, NA), 
               y2014 = c(13216000, 19921000, 1.93, NA, NA, NA), 
               y2015 = c(14331000L, 21227000L, 2L, 40811L, 48190L, NA), 
               y2016 = c(14708000, 22210000, 2.06, 559094, 233141, 10.84), 
               y2017 = c(13823000, 21329000, 2.01, 786806, 299230, 12.86), 
               y2018 = c(13917000, 21772000, 1.91, 814462, 307252, 11.76), 
               y2019 = c(14256000, 21820000, 1.87, 920734, 368575, 11.24), 
               y2020 = c(5880000, 10765000, 1.09, 485423, 326465, 5.57)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame" ))
  
    library(tidyr)  
    x %>% 
      pivot_longer(-c(id_isin, covariate) ) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = "covariate") %>%
      mutate(year = as.numeric(stringr::str_remove(name, "y")))%>%
      select(id_isin, year, `NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS`, `OPERATING INCOME`)
```

Which gives us the following:

```
    # A tibble: 22 × 4
   id_isin       year `NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS` `OPERATING INCOME`
   <chr>        <dbl>                          <dbl>              <dbl>
 1 ZAE000255915  2010                        8118000           11756000
 2 ZAE000255915  2011                        9674000           14134000
 3 ZAE000255915  2012                        8393000           12266000
 4 ZAE000255915  2013                       11981000           17975000
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(id_isin = c("ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", "ZAE000255915", 
                           "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289", "ZAE000198289"), 
               covariate = c("NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS", 
                             "OPERATING INCOME", "RETURN ON ASSETS", "NET INC BEFORE EXTRA/PFD DIVS", 
                             "OPERATING INCOME", "RETURN ON ASSETS"), 
               y2010 = c(8118000, 11756000, 2.5, NA, NA, NA), 
               y2011 = c(9674000, 14134000, 2.3, NA, NA, NA), 
               y2012 = c(8393000, 12266000, 1.78, NA, NA, NA), 
               y2013 = c(11981000, 17975000, 1.84, NA, NA, NA), 
               y2014 = c(13216000, 19921000, 1.93, NA, NA, NA), 
               y2015 = c(14331000L, 21227000L, 2L, 40811L, 48190L, NA), 
               y2016 = c(14708000, 22210000, 2.06, 559094, 233141, 10.84), 
               y2017 = c(13823000, 21329000, 2.01, 786806, 299230, 12.86), 
               y2018 = c(13917000, 21772000, 1.91, 814462, 307252, 11.76), 
               y2019 = c(14256000, 21820000, 1.87, 920734, 368575, 11.24), 
               y2020 = c(5880000, 10765000, 1.09, 485423, 326465, 5.57)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame" ))


df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(paste("y",2010:2020,sep = "")), names_to = "year", values_to = "HHA") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "covariate", values_from = "HHA") %>% 
  mutate(`NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS` = coalesce(`NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS`,`NET INC BEFORE EXTRA/PFD DIVS`),
         year = str_remove(year, "y")) %>% 
  select(-`NET INC BEFORE EXTRA/PFD DIVS`)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 22 x 5
   id_isin      year  `NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS` `OPERATING INCOME` `RETURN ON ASSETS`
   <chr>        <chr>                          <dbl>              <dbl>              <dbl>
 1 ZAE000255915 2010                         8118000           11756000               2.5 
 2 ZAE000255915 2011                         9674000           14134000               2.3 
 3 ZAE000255915 2012                         8393000           12266000               1.78
 4 ZAE000255915 2013                        11981000           17975000               1.84
 5 ZAE000255915 2014                        13216000           19921000               1.93
 6 ZAE000255915 2015                        14331000           21227000               2   
 7 ZAE000255915 2016                        14708000           22210000               2.06
 8 ZAE000255915 2017                        13823000           21329000               2.01
 9 ZAE000255915 2018                        13917000           21772000               1.91
10 ZAE000255915 2019                        14256000           21820000               1.87
# ... with 12 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

concise data.table approach (`x` is your input structure, above):

```
dcast(melt(
  x[,covariate:=fifelse(
    grepl("^NET",covariate),
    "NET INC BEFORE_EXTRA/PFDDIVS",
    covariate)],
  ,id=c(1,2),variable.name = "year")[
    ,year:=as.integer(gsub("y","",year))],
  id_isin+year~covariate,value.var = "value"
)
```